# Xcode build failed - no such file or directory

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

my build failed in Xcode 5 with the following error!  error: /Users/yilly288/Desktop/Jokes v1.3/Resources/icons/Icon-72.png: No such file or director
there are 2 other errors the same with different icon sizes, Thank you kindly in advance.

Comment: What's the path to your Icon files? Did they get moved?

Answer (score 0):

Xcode cannot find images for icons, check if they exist in the project folder, and if not, add them.

Answer (score 0):

command+1 to show project navigator, then input the "Icon-72.png" in the search field which at  at left bottom. You can see "Icon-72.png" is marked redColor in project. delete it, add again if you really need it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have dragged images in your xcode and forgot to check mark copy items option. Please check.